# TFS: How to Block/Restrict A Branch From Merging Back to Main?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, integration, restrict

I have a main branch and some child branches, one of the child branches is an OEM build and is not supposed to merge back to main, but the other child branches should be able to do that.

At this moment, it's up to the person performing the merge to follow the rule, but human make mistakes, I'd like to know if there are some settings can force the rule? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  But if it ever happens accidentally you can always Rollback the changeset that merged the changes.  You can also setup alerts on MAIN so that you can be notified when changes are made and can review them.